# show whether or not the following statement is true: "The set of rational numbers Q is connected"

Tags: general-topology

if we consider the set $G =\Bbb Q$ where $\Bbb Q$ is the set of rational numbers, it can be shown that $G$ is not connected

Let  $A_1 =\{x \in{R} : x< \sqrt{2} \}$ and
$B_1 = \{x \in{R} : x> \sqrt{2}\}$ it is then that $A_1 $ and $B_1$ open disjoint and their union is $G$ therefore $G$ is not connected. Will it be like this?

I do not pretend that they solve my tasks, I have been investigating. I need to explain to me step by step how I can show that a discrete metric space of more than one point is totally disconnected and locally connected.
Let $A$ and $B$ be connected and $ A \subset B$ if $C$ is a component of $A - B$, show that $B - C$ is connected.
Please, I know you can help me.

Comment: I do not understand several things in your post but an easy way to see why the rationals are not connected is to observe that between any two rationals, you can find an irrational. So fix an irrational $p$ and argue that $(-\infty,p)\cup(p,\infty)$ forms a separation of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: MathJax uses { and } for formatting; to get them as symbols use `\{` ($\{$) and `\}` ($\}$). Your $A_1$ and $B_1$ aren’t subsets of $\Bbb Q$: you need to change their definitions to $A_1=\{x\in\color{red}{\Bbb Q}:x<\sqrt2\}$ and $B_1=\{x\in\color{red}{\Bbb Q}:x>\sqrt2\}$. Then they will indeed be disjoint open subsets of $\Bbb Q$ whose union is $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I wanted to place it that way but I don't handle latex very well, if this is correct? How can I prove the other points please? you can help?

Comment: I would write $x^2 < 2$ rather than $x < \sqrt{2}$ since it doesn't require numbers outside of $\mathbb{Q}$. I would also just use $A$ and $B$ instead of $A_1$ and $B_1$ since the additional notation adds nothing to your argument. You have correctly argued that they are both open sets and disjoint which is the definition of disconnected. To prove it is totally disconnected you can use that the irrationals are dense in the reals. Finally if you right click on the latex parts of a post you can choose "Show Math As -> Tex Commands" to see how it was done.

Comment: Thank you very much I will take it into account. Can you help me and explain the other demos? please i need the help.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: However, Rosa’s separation using $\sqrt2$ is nicer from an intuitive point of view, and since we’re not in the business of constructing $\Bbb R$, there’s no pressing reason to tie one hand behind our backs by insisting on using only rationals in defining subsets of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Rosa: It would be better to ask the other questions as separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solution will be "like that", but you have to be more precise:

Use $A_1 = \{x \in \Bbb Q: x < \sqrt{2})=(-\infty, \sqrt{2}) \cap \Bbb Q$, where the open segment is taken in $\Bbb R$ and is open there so that $A_1$ is open in the subspace topology on $\Bbb Q$. And similarly $A_2 = \{x \in \Bbb Q: x > \sqrt{2})=(\sqrt{2}, +\infty) \cap \Bbb Q$ is open in $\Bbb Q$ too. You could also use $\{x \in \Bbb Q\mid x^2 < 2\}$ and $\{x \in \Bbb Q\mid x^2 > 2\}$ if don't want to refer to a non-rational like $\sqrt{2}$. But you can assume we have constructed and know about $\Bbb R$ here and use that to our advantage..